# Defining a form action on an Image

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<img src=\"{$recipe['image']}\" height=100 width=100 /><br />";
echo '<form action="php/recipe.php?id='.$recipe_id.'" method="POST">';
echo '<input id="search" name="Look" type="Submit" value="Look" >';
echo '</form>';
```

How do I go about using this form action with the image src rather than the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try anchor tag `<a>` here, because when you click on that image it will redirect to `recipe.php` page and you will get the `recipe_id`

```
echo "<a href='php/recipe.php?id=$recipe_id'><img src=\"{$recipe['image']}\" height=100 width=100 /></a><br />";
```